# How to show for any symmetric matrices the quadratic mean of eigenvalues less than square of Frobenius norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix which has $k$ non-zero eigenvalue. Show that the square of Frobenius norm is always bigger than the average of squared eigenvalues. That is:

$$\|A\|_F^2 \geq \frac{1}{k} (\sum_{i=1}^k |\lambda_i|)^2$$

My try: applying $\|A\|_F^2=\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i^2$.

Also, do we have the correspondence of this in a vector form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
k^{-1}\|A\|_F^2 = k^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i^2 \ge \left(k^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{k}|\lambda_i| \right)^2 
\end{align*}
by the inequality between quadratic means and arithmetic means. Another proof would be, with $\mathbf{\lambda} = (|\lambda_1|, \cdots, |\lambda_k|)$ and $\mathbf{1} = (1, \cdots, 1)$, we have
\begin{align*}
\|A\|_F^2 = k^{-1}(\mathbf{\lambda}^\intercal\mathbf{\lambda})(\mathbf{1}^\intercal\mathbf{1}) \ge k^{-1} (\mathbf{\lambda}^\intercal \mathbf{1})^2 = k^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|\lambda_i|\right)^2
\end{align*}
by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: The second proof makes sense to me, but could you elaborate how we can use AM-GM to get the result because we have no multiplication hear?

Comment: The first proof uses AM-QM, not AM-GM. AM-QM is actually proved through exactly the same steps as seen with the CS proof seen in the second proof.

Comment: The second proof both $k^-1$ gets cancelled and does not give the claim? Can you elaborate that?

Comment: Oops, typo, the first $k^{-1}$ was not meant to be there.  Fixed.